# Unhide workspace switcher in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-18.04

In ubuntu 18.04, when you open Activities, the workspace bar is hidden. It pops out only after you hover your mouse over it. Is there a way to make it always popped? - so that when you press Activities you can see all your workspaces at a glance.

Comment: That should go to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Thanks. Done that. For those who ended up here, I used Expand workspaces switcher extension from here. [https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1351/show-workspaces/]. Hope this helps.